# Overloading operator new for a class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

When we overload new operator of a class, we declare the function as a member function.
For eg:

```
class OpNew {
public:
    OpNew() { cout << "OpNew::OpNew()" << endl;}
    void* operator new(size_t sz) {
         cout << "OpNew::new: "
            << sz << " bytes" << endl;
         return ::new char[sz];
    }
};
```

How does the statement `OpNew *obj = new OpNew` work under the hood ? as overloaded new is a member of OpNew class not a static. So how does compiler ensure this call to `new` member  function succeeds?

Comment: I hope you overloaded `operator delete` as well, otherwise you've got undefined behavior.

Comment: Of course I did, that was just a snippet :)

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov What should be static? operator new is always static; you don't have to declare it static (and I'm not even sure it's legal to do so).

Comment: @James, yes, `operator new` and `operator delete`. They are implicitly `static`. It is legal to declare that explicitly. That should have been required from the get-go to avoid exactly this soft of confusion.

Comment: Overloaded operator new returns void*. How come that in statement `OpNew *obj = new OpNew` we got conversion void* -> OpNew*? Such coversions cant be done implicitly in C++, can they?

Comment: @Givi: The `void*` is consumed by C++ itself, it is not "converted" to `T*`.  An object is created inside that memory (requiring a constructor call), and a pointer to the new object is returned to the program.  Do not confuse `T::operator new(sizeof T)` and `new T` -- the first is only a very small part of what the second entails.

Comment: @sharptooth More Effective C++ is the source for the strict advice: _when you write a **placement version** of operator new, be sure to write the corresponding **placement version** of operator delete_ (quoting from Effective C++, my emphasis). Seems that for just overloading the non-placement version of the new operator it is not mandatory to overload also delete. Which make sense if you go over the reasons mentioned in Item 52.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[An `operator new()` or `operator new[]()` for a class is always a static class member, even if it is not declared with the keyword static.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr381.htm)

What the C++ standard says (draft n3242), in section `[class.free]`:

> Any allocation function for a class `T` is a static member (even if not explicitly declared `static`).