# Overloading new() per class- rather than globally

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I understand to overload the global new operator you can do this and all classes will use it:

```
void *operator new(size_t size){
    if(void *mem = malloc(size)){
        cout << "allocated memory" << endl;
        return mem;
    }
    else{
        throw bad_alloc();
    }
}
```

but how would I overload new() on a **per-class basis**? So a different implementation of new() for class X,Y and Z?

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406199/overloading-operator-new-for-a-class

Comment: The edit to my question doesn't make it obvious the code remains the same. It is much clearer to see Mats Petersson's reply below, along with my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just declare it `static`:

```
 class X
 {
    static void *operator new(size_t size) {
        if(void *mem = malloc(size)){
            cout << "allocated memory" << endl;
            return mem;
        }
        else{
           throw bad_alloc();
       }
    }
  };
```

We're done.

Comment: and if I wanted every class to use the implementation in my question, declare it globally and then for any classes I wish to use different, just do what you have done and declare as static?

Comment: @user997112: Yes, that should work. Any class that inherits from X will also use this `operator new` unless there is one in the derived class. And of course, you need to declare a corresponding `delete`, or things will go very wrong very quickly.

Comment: 'Static' is implied anyway. What you really need to say is 'declare it inside the class'.